# T-SQL Better way to determine max of date (accounting for nulls)

Tags: t-sql

I am comparing two dates and trying to determine the max of the two dates. A null date would be considered less than a valid date. I am using the following case statement, which works - but feels very inefficient and clunky. Is there a better way?

```
update @TEMP_EARNED
set nextearn = case when lastoccurrence is null and lastearned is null then null
                   when lastoccurrence is null then lastearned
                   when lastearned is null then lastoccurrence
                   when lastoccurrence > lastearned then lastoccurrence
                   else lastearned end;
```

(This is in MS SQL 2000, FYI.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select c1, c2, 
       case when c1 > c2 then c1 else coalesce(c2,c1) end as max 
from twocol;
+------+------+------+
| c1   | c2   | max  |
+------+------+------+
| NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL |    2 |    2 |
|    1 | NULL |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |    2 |
| NULL | NULL | NULL |
|    2 | NULL |    2 |
| NULL |    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    1 |    2 |
+------+------+------+
```

Why does this work? if neither operand is null, then we get a "normal" comparison: the "then" branch when c1 > c2, the else branch when c1 <= c2.

On the "else" branch, we call coalesce, but as its first argument is the non-null c2, we return c2.

.

But if either operand is null, the test `c1 > c2` evaluates to false, and we return `coalesce( c2, c1 )`.

If the null operand was c1, we get c2, which is what we want because we are (for this question) calling null is "less than" any non-null value.

If the null operand was c2, we get c1. That's fine, because c1 is either not null, and thus (for this question) "greater than" the null c2, ***or...***

If both operands were null, we get c1, but it doesn't matter which we get, as both are null.

> An additional advantage is that this idiom works for any types for which `operator >` works, without further thought or details.

Answer (score 4):

The earliest date SQL Server can store in a datetime field is 1st Jan 1753, so if you just count nulls as that date then you can do it in a single line:

```
set nextearn = case when coalesce(lastoccurrence, '1753-01-01 00:00') > coalesce(lastearned, '1753-01-01 00:00') then lastoccurrence else lastearned end;
```

If your field is a smalldatetime then the minimum is 1st Jan 1900 so it would be:

```
set nextearn = case when coalesce(lastoccurrence, '1900-01-01 00:00') > coalesce(lastearned, '1900-01-01 00:00') then lastoccurrence else lastearned end;
```

Comment: For a SQL Server field of datetime, the earliest date that can be stored is January 1, 1753, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx. Smalldatetime's minimum is Jan 1, 1900. So the value to use in the text string for minimum is dependent on the type.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Set nextearn = Case When IsNull(lastoccurrence, 0) > IsNull(lastearned , 0) 
               Then lastoccurrence Else lastearned  End
```

All dates in sql server are stored as two integers, opne that represents the date (number of days since 1 jan 1900) and thh other that represents the time (number of seconds [SmallDatetime] or milleseconds[DateTime] since midnight)...

The two numbers are combined as a Integer.DecimalFraction (DateInteger.TimePortion).
 So the number 0.0 represents Midnight 1 Jan 1900, 2.5 represents noon on 3 Jan 1900, etc...

Using the number in your expression eliminates the need to parse the string representation into a number before comparing it with the number which represents the other date...